# Negative voltage on input pins

Tags: voltage, gpio, negative

Hope that someone can help me:

I found a schematics to program microcontroller from Raspberry PI (http://mujweb.cz/tlc/rpp/) and modified it a bit (will use direct 12V and 5V power supply).

I'm trying to put it on breadboard before ordering a PCB, but found out, that GPIO4 and GPIO7 pins has ~(-1.5V) in this schematic when I add GND (no need to add 12 or 5V).

[image: schematics]

Maybe someone can see the issue from scheme? 
And if there is anything else wrong, please note :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to ask you a pretty serious question. Why in the world are you futzing around with microcontrollers that require VDD programming pulses when today there are a plethora of microcontrollers available that program when connected to their normal +3.3V or 5V supply with nothing more than a low cost USB adapter to a PC? Today most of these microcontrollers also support on chip debugging with breakpoints and memory inspection features that make those old VDD programmed MCUs look sick in comparison. Time to be in 2015 and not 1987.

Comment: Long story short: For fun!

Comment: I added 100K resistor between GPIO4 and GND before R1. It solved the problem with GPIO4, but is this the right way?? Maybe there is better solution?

Comment: You would have to take a look at the waveforms on an o-scope to see why adding the pull down resistor made a difference. Possibly the waveform was being affected by node capacitance and the transistor was not turning off fully. The pulldown skewed the waveform enough to allow the NPN to turn off and on.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that are necessary for this to work.

1) You need to make sure that the GND of the PI board is connected into the GND of the direct power supplies.

2) You need to make sure that the the two schematic symbols below actually connect together.

[image]   <== ??? ==>    [image]

Comment: Thanks for your time, but when I connect RPI ground with GND nothing changes!

About point 2 - its connected!